# EPERM installing KuduSync on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, file-permissions, kudu

I'm experiencing an 'EPERM' error trying to install KuduSync globally either from the Kudu debug console or automatically from the deploy.cmd file.

Here's the error log when I try to run `npm install -g kudusync` from the debug console:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/kudusync
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/kudusync
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EPERM, rmdir 'D:\Program Files (    x86)\nodejs\0.10.5\node_modules\kudusync'

npm ERR! error rolling back  kudusync@0.1.24 { [Error: EPERM, rmdir 'D:\Program Files (    x86)\nodejs\0.10.5\node_modules\kudusync']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 50,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'D:\\Program Files (    x86)\\nodejs\\0.10.5\\node_modules\\kudusync' }
npm ERR! Error: EPERM, rmdir 'D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\0.10.5\node_modules\kudusync'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, rmdir 'D:\Program Files (    x86)\nodejs\0.10.5\node_modules\kudusync']
npm ERR!   errno: 50,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   path: 'D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\0.10.5\\node_modules\\kudusync' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "node" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\1.2.18\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-    cli.js" "install" "-g" "kudusync"
npm ERR! cwd D:\home
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.5
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! path D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\0.10.5\node_modules\kudusync
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno 50
npm ERR! stack Error: EPERM, rmdir 'D:\Program Files (    x86)\nodejs\0.10.5\node_modules\kudusync'
npm ERR! Error: EPERM, open 'D:\home\npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, open 'D:\home\npm-debug.log'] errno: 50, code: 'EPERM', path:     'D:\\home\\npm-debug.log' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "node" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\1.2.18\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-    cli.js" "install" "-g" "kudusync"
npm ERR! cwd D:\home
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.5
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! path D:\home\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno 50
npm ERR! stack Error: EPERM, open 'D:\home\npm-debug.log'
```

Has someone already experienced and solved this issue ?
Thanks!

### EDIT

Upon further searching I discovered that the folder the system is trying to remove doesn't exist, neither its parent, the path ends at `D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\0.10.5\`. Any clue ?

Comment: I think the error is self explanatory, may be you don't have permission to the directory. Not sure but windows has some UAC enabled that may cause the permission problems in system directories.

Comment: Thanks @Салман, I've extended the question with some extra details as it seems that I'm dealing with some kind of NodeJS path issues.

Comment: Well, I can't think why its doing it. But I'd say create those directory there and let it be happy deleting them. ;)